# Count requests and update request header in requests.Session

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm writing a python client for a RESTful API that requires a special header to be passed on each request. The header has the form: `X-Seq-Count: n`, where `n` is the sequential number of the request: first made request should have the header `X-Seq-Count: 1` be present, the second one should have `X-Seq-Count: 2` etc.

I'm using the `requests` library to handle the low level HTTP calls. What would be the best approach to track the amount of requests made and inject the custom header? What I came up with is subclassing the `requests.Session` and overriding the `Session.prepare_request` method:

```
class CustomSession(requests.Session):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.requests_count = 0

    def prepare_request(self, request):
        # increment requests counter
        self.requests_count += 1
        # update the header
        self.headers['X-Seq-Count'] = str(self.requests_count)
        return super().prepare_request(request)
```

Hovewer, I'm not very happy with subclassing `Session`. Is there a better way? I stumbled upon the [`event hooks`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#event-hooks) in the docs, but unsure how to use them - looking at the source code, it seems that the hooks can only be applied to the response object, not the request object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as an alternative, you can take advantage of auth mechanism of `requests`, you can modify the prepared `Request` object:

```
def auth_provider(req):
    global requests_count
    requests_count += 1
    req.headers['X-Seq-Count'] = requests_count
    print('requests_count:', requests_count)
    return req

requests_count = 0
s = requests.Session()
s.auth = auth_provider

s.get('https://www.example.com')
requests.get('https://www.example.com', auth=auth_provider)
```

output:

```
requests_count: 1
requests_count: 2
```

however subclassing `Session` sounds okay to me.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion! the fact that the auth is actually able to modify the request before it is sent never came to my mind. Let me try it out later today.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I must abandon `requests` as I need to do a websocket upgrade so I am switching to `aiohttp`'s `ClientSession` instead. Nevertheless, I will accept your answer as it is a working solution - maybe someday it will help somebody looking for an answer!